# Is it possible for Windows 7 to differentiate between files created by a process run by a user and files created by a user?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, file-permissions

## A File Created by a Process that is Run by a User

For example, I use my user account to run a process which creates a bunch of files.

## A File Created by a User

I copy a file, or create a file using the command prompt or the GUI.

My guess would be that [this could be done with permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/351390/windows-server-role-of-system-and-creator-owner-users), but I'm not entirely certain that it does happen, unless you're running the process as an administrator.

My goal here is to figure out the difference between the two, so that at the end of the day I can audit which files I created and delete any files I do not need at the end of the day.

Comment: Have you audited what the 'Modified By' attribute is for files created by both processes you list above?

Comment: It would be my user name...in either case and same with `created by`

Comment: I am going to say that what you are asking is not possible unless you can run your process by a different user.  Perhaps open the command prompt under a different user or Administrator so that when your files are created, the 'Modified By' will be different.

Comment: Unix has the concept of _SetUID_ and _SetGID_ permissions, where a program runs with the attributes of its owner/group. I don't know if the Pro versions of Win7 have this, but if not you should be able to achieve it by running all your processes through launch shells or links which call `RunAs` to execute each process as an identifiable user (you would need to set permissions carefully to stop the users calling the processes direct). Alternatively, you could run your processes as services with appropriate log on settings.

Comment: All files are created by a process run by the user.  Even if that process is just Windows Explorer or CMD.EXE.  You'll have trouble trying to identify the process that created the file.

Comment: Hmm that seems to a feature of an OS that is lacking, being able to tell could be pretty useful.